# Why is it strongly recommended to not override lifecycle methods of Activities or Fragments?

Tags: android

[image]
Why is it strongly recommended? Maybe because otherwise you have to use boilerplate, for example, "super.onResume()"?
https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations#lifecycle

Comment: Seems that this is a detailed explanation to your question: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Google is just trying to make up for the poor implementation of lifecycle in fragments. Since fragments take up the Lifecycle of their parent activity. Hence the need to implement a lifecycle observer which also needs the lifecycle owner in the parameters. I will further look into this...